# DataGridView checkbox column "select all" performance

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a checkbox column. I'm trying to create a select/deselect all button. The code for changing the values is easy enough, but the performance is horrendous.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Selected"].Value = _selectAll;
}
```

_selectAll is simply a toggle bool variable. Is there a better way to do this where the performance is fast? I've tried changing the value in the underlying DataTable as well. It still takes several seconds for just a few hundred rows, but most work will be done on  thousands of rows.

**EDIT & SOLUTION (2011/10/4)**

The main problem was in the DGV properties. Once I set,

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

performance improved dramatically (per [MSDN DataGridView Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx)).
The solutions suggested as of this edit would also improve performance slightly.

Comment: Try accessing the column by index instead of by name. e.g. `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = _selectAll;`

Comment: Do you have grid bounded to any property or just giving it from the code behind?

Comment: Are you sure that is where the bottle neck is?  Me thinks it is elsewhere.

Comment: @Steve Wellens : Aha! The elsewhere turns out to be the DGV properties. 'dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;' fixed the issue (per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx). _Please post this as answer for future viewers._

Comment: awesome work :) saved me today ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks a lot, by setting the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` property

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

the performance is much better...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a common problem. 
First, do you have any processing associated with the Checkbox checked change?
If so, create a bool member variable.
Initialize it to false before performing the Select All / Deselect All. 
In the CheckBox checked change event -> check for the value of the bool paramter.
If it comes with false return from the event. Dont process anything.
After completing the for looping to set the select all / Deselect All, process the checked change event if necessary. 
Dont forget to reset the bool parameter to true after for loop.

```
bool _allowProcessing = false;
//SelectAll / Deselect All
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
   dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = _selectAll;
}
_allowProcessing = true;
// Do some processing if required

// Checked change event
public void CheckBox_CheckedChange(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
  if(!_allowProcessing)
    return;

  // Do Processing
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the most complete solution of those suggested. Please note the edit in my question which addresses the main reason for the poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'll get a performance boost or not, but something else you can try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    dgv["Selected", i].Value = _selectAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the gridview column name, u can specify which column it belongs to.This will work faster. Hope it helps.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
   dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = _selectAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I show another way to improve this problem.
Accessing datagridview directly like `dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Selected"].Value` makes datagridview slowly.

So, changing datasource and refreshing datagridview makes match better performance if your datagridview has datasource and the datasouce has checked status.

```
foreach (var item in yourDataSource)
{
    item.Checked = _selectAll;
}
dgv.Invalidate();
```